# How to define stash issue regex to match only from begining?

Tags: regex, commit, git-stash

The default regex in Stash to match JIRA ID is

```
JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="-Dintegration.jira.key.pattern=\"((?<!([a-z]{1,10})-?)[a-z]+-\d+)\""
```

But it matches regardless where the JIRA ID's location.

I want it only matches from beginning:

- JIRA-1 what ever:   match!
- something JIRA-1 else:    not match

How to edit the regex?

Following don't work

```
\"^((?<!([a-z]{1,10})-?)[a-z]+-\d+)\"
```

and

```
\"(^(?<!([a-z]{1,10})-?)[a-z]+-\d+)\"
```

Solution:

^[a-z]+-\d+ will do.

Comment: Try this: /^JIRA-(\d+) /

Comment: It is the look-behind that does not let you match that text. Remove it, and use `(?i)^[a-z]+-\d+`. Or if `JIRA` must start the string, `^JIRA-\d+`.

Comment: Does either of my suggestions work for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the `JIRA-<id>` only from the beginning you should try:

```
\"^JIRA-(\d+)\"
```